# How to access the CustomTaskPanes property aof a VSTO AddIn from a shared library?

Tags: c#, shared-libraries, vsto, customtaskpane

I am building an AddIn for Word, Excel, PowerPoint. This AddIn comes with a ribbon. Whenever the user clicks a button on the ribbon a custom task pane is opened on the side. Since I do not want to rewrite the same code in three different projects I have a shared project where my ribbon is defined (XML).

Problem: the ribbon callbacks have to access the `CustomTaskPanes` property.

I have tried to inject the `CustomTaskPanes` property to the shared ribbon:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
  protected override Office.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
  {
    return new Shared.Ribbon(this.CustomTaskPanes);
  }
}

public class Ribbon : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
{
  private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPaneCollection taskPanes;

  public Ribbon(Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPaneCollection taskPanes)
  {
    this.taskPanes = taskPanes;
  }
}
```

But at the time when this method is executed the `CustomTaskPanes` property is `null`which means I am injecting `null`.

Changing the constructor of the ribbon so that we can inject the AddIn to the ribbon does not work, too, since `CustomTaskPanes` property is internal the code throws an exception:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
  protected override Office.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
  {
    return new Shared.Ribbon(this);
  }
}

public class RecordsRibbon : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
{
  private dynamic addIn;

  public RecordsRibbon(dynamic addIn)
  {
    this.addIn = addIn;
  }

  private void OpenTaskPane()
  {
    // RuntimeBinderException with message: 'ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes' is
    // inaccessible due to its protection level
    var taskPane = this.addIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new UserControl(), "title");
    var taskPane.Width = 400;
    var taskPane.Visible = true;
  }
}
```

I do not want to change the access modifier of the `ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes` property since it is designer generated code.

I also tried reflection which results in `MissingMethodException`.

```
  System.Type t = this.addIn.GetType();
  var ctps = t.InvokeMember(
    "get_CustomTaskPanes",
     BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
     null,
     this.addIn,
     null);
  var ctps = t.InvokeMember(
    "get_CustomTaskPanes",
     BindingFlags.GetProperty| BindingFlags.NonPublic,
     null,
     this.addIn,
     null);
  var ctps = t.InvokeMember(
    "CustomTaskPanes",
     BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
     null,
     this.addIn,
     null);
```

What else can I do to access the custom task panes collection of the AddIn from the shared library?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this workaround here? http://davecra.wordpress.com/2013/05/21/customtaskpanes-in-a-net-shared-com-add-in/

Comment: As far as I have understood the post it tells that I have to build a shared AddIn. There I have to wire up the Office connections and also implement some interfaces like the one for the custom task pane collection. Too much work. I have a shared ribbon which will be consumed by different VSTOs. The connection and implementation of the Office interfaces are all done by VS. Therefore I have decided to add a public MyCustomTaskPanes to each ThisAddIn class. That property just returns the internal CustomTaskPanes. This way injecting the ThisAddIn and accessing this.addIn.MyCustomTaskPanes works.